# How do I make sure my Python 3.6 code is compatible with other minor versions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I'm writing a python package in python 3.6, then how do I ensure my code can be downloaded and ran in other python 3 environments, like python 3.5?

What makes some python packages (e.g. [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow)) compatible with all python 3 minor versions, while other python packages (e.g. [OpenAI Gym](https://github.com/openai/gym)) only compatible with Python 3.5?

Finally: if my goal is to write code that is compatible for Python 3.5 and 3.6, then would it be better to just use a python 3.5 environment?

Comment: [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The glib-but-true answer:
**Test your 3.6 code with those other versions of Python.**
If you want to see if something runs correctly in environment *X*, there's no substitute for actually running it in environment *X*.

[Tox](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tox)
is a Python testing framework designed to do exactly this on your workstation.
Something like this is often part of a larger
[continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)
framework or service, which might be hosted on a remote server.

Writing your code in the earliest syntax you need to support is always a good idea, but it's not enough.
You still need to test *later* versions, because functions or classes can change, and even bug-fixes can break your code if you were unwittingly depending on their behavior.

---

As for why some packages don't work under a specific minor version, the most likely reason is that they **use a Python language feature that was introduced later**.
(Possibly it's one of their dependencies that requires the language feature.)
This can include language syntax changes like
Python 3.5's
[`@` matrix-multiplication operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-465),
all the way down to seeming trivia like
Python 3.1's
[printing commas as thousands-separators](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.1.html#pep-378-format-specifier-for-thousands-separator),
which is still enough to raise an exception.

It's actually a bit more complicated than just
"supports version *x* or greater",
because there are some gaps in Python's history.
The most likely headache is the `u''` Unicode literal syntax from Python 2.
It was removed in Python 3.0...
and then
[restored in Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#summary-release-highlights),
after its absence caused more grief than expected.
That one change means any script with a `u'Unicode literal'` could work under Python 2.7 and 3.3+ while *not* working under Python 3.0, 3.1, or 3.2.

The Python documentation is very good about keeping track of when a feature was introduced.
For instance, the first thing the
[`typing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-typing)
tells you is:

> **26.1. `typing` - Support for type hints**
>
> *New in version 3.5.*

A `Ctrl-F` style search for "new in" or "changed in" will generally turn up all the most important changes.